# Handling resource file paths in JAR's and development

Tags: java, maven-2, jar

I have a keystore file that I want available to several classes in my application.  I made a .config file that points the name of the keystore file, it's password, and other information.

It's a Maven-based project, so the keystore is in /src/main/resources.  I build a jar and move the file to /resources in the jar.  I'd like the .config file to say something like "resources/keystore.jks".

How do I parse the .config file so it:

1. Uses /src/main/resources/keystore.jks for application code in development.
2. Uses /src/test/resources/keystore.jks for test code.
3. Uses /resources in the jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's a Maven-based project, so the keystore is in /src/main/resources. I build a jar and move the file to /resources in the jar. I'd like the .config file to say something like "resources/keystore.jks".

Why do you do that? You shouldn't have to move it. Just put that keystore in `resources/resources/keystore.jks` if you want it to be available in `/resources` on the classpath.

> How do I parse the .config file so it:
>
> 1. Uses /src/main/resources/keystore.jks for
>      application code in development.
> 2. Uses /src/test/resources/keystore.jks for
>      test code.
> 3. Uses /resources in the jar.

If you follow my previous advice, then you don't have anything particular to do.

1. Resources in `src/main/resources` are available in the normal classpath
2. Resources in `src/test/resources` are available in the test classpath (which has precedence on the normal classpath when runnign `mvn test`)
3. `src/main/resources` is the root of the resource path. If you want something to be available under `/my/package/my.properties`, then put in `src/main/resources/my/package/my.properties`.

If really this doesn't cover your needs, then have a look at [resources filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Filtering can be combined with [profiles](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) for more complicated things. Or you could also use several filters and pick up the right one by passing a property. But, as I said, I'm not sure you need this.